# JCarousel não funciona control next prev

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código em jquery, ele faz corretamente o carousel, mas não funciona o next e o prev. Preciso criar eles dinamicamente. O que será que pode ser?

Arquivo jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3czuosLg/